# QT C2064, having issues when using my class's variables yet it works outside of the class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, the code in the `on_openButton_clicked` function runs and works as intended, now I'm trying to use classes for everything and its throwing the following error :

> C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "getfile.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void getFileInfo::setFileInfo(QString dir)
{
    textFile = dir;

    file(textFile);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        return;
    }

    fileInfo(file);
    fileStream(&file);
    nameOfFile(fileInfo.fileName()), fileText = fileStream.readAll();
}
void MainWindow::on_openButton_clicked()
{
    getFileInfo classFile;
    QString textFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Text Document", "C://", "*.txt");
    classFile.setFileInfo(textFile);

   // ui->labelFilePath->setText("File Path: " + file.fileName());
    //ui->labelFileName->setText(nameOfFile);
    //ui->textBox->setPlainText(fileText);
}

void MainWindow::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileDirectory = ui->labelFilePath->text(), textFile;
    if (fileDirectory != "File Path: ")
        textFile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save Text Document", fileDirectory, "*.txt");
    else
        textFile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save Text Document", "C://", "*.txt");

    QFile file(textFile);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QTextStream fileStream(&file);
        fileStream << ui->textBox->toPlainText() << endl << endl << endl << "Time Since Edit: ";
    }
}
```

**getfile.h**

```
#ifndef GETFILE_H
#define GETFILE_H

#endif // GETFILE_H

#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>

class getFileInfo
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setFileInfo(QString dir);

private:
    QString textFile, nameOfFile, fileText;
    QFile file;
    QFileInfo fileInfo;
    QTextStream fileStream;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp ( earlier working version before using classes )**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_openButton_clicked()
{
    QString textFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Text Document", "C://", "*.txt");
    QFile file(textFile);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Could Not Open File\nOr\nNo File Selected");
        return;
    }

    QFileInfo fileInfo(file);
    QTextStream fileStream(&file);
    QString nameOfFile(fileInfo.fileName()), fileText = fileStream.readAll();

    ui->labelFilePath->setText("File Path: " + file.fileName());
    ui->labelFileName->setText(nameOfFile);
    ui->textBox->setPlainText(fileText);
}

void MainWindow::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileDirectory = ui->labelFilePath->text(), textFile;
    if (fileDirectory != "File Path: ")
        textFile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save Text Document", fileDirectory, "*.txt");
    else
        textFile = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save Text Document", "C://", "*.txt");

    QFile file(textFile);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QTextStream fileStream(&file);
        fileStream << ui->textBox->toPlainText() << endl << endl << endl << "Time Since Edit: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message, and indicate which line in the source it refers to.

Comment: remove `Q_OBJECT` in `getFileInfo`, 
only the classes that inherit from QObject must have that macro, in your case it is not necessary to do that in the getFileInfo class.

Comment: BTW, `#endif // GETFILE_H` should be the very last line of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in these lines ?

```
file(textFile);
...
fileInfo(file);
...
fileStream(&file);
```

in `file(textFile)` you want to call `operator()(const QString&)` on `QFile` object, but `QFile` class doesn't have that method. The same with `fileInfo(file)` and `fileStream(&file)`, `QFileInfo` doesn't have `operator()(const QFile&)` method etc.

All objects `file`, `fileInfo` and `fileStream` are members of your class, so they were created in constructor of `getFileInfo` class. After they were constructed, you can use *setters* method to set paremeters. So call

```
file.setFileName(textFile);
fileInfo.setFile(file);
fileStream.setDevice(&file);
```

Comment: that solved it, thank you for the help!